# Use jQuery ID Selector with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, html-table, twitch

## I'm actually creating a list with streamers and checking if they're online, if so they'll get a green background color.

Now I want to create an additional list next to my "team list" which includes **every** streamer.

---

For this I'm trying to use the same method like the one I'm using for the background color.

```
$(".".concat(user)).css("background-color","lightgrey");
```

*(to color every background color for the streamers)*

But now I want to just hide the streamers in **one** list and **not everywhere.**

**So I can't use this:**

```
$(".".concat(user)).css("display", "none");
```

*(would hide **every** offline streamer in **every list**)*

---

I already tried to apply the ID but actually I don't know how.
If I use this:

```
$("#online".concat(user)).css("display", "none");
```

nothing happens.

*(I named my ID online)*

```
<tr class="header" id ="online">
```

*(I already tried to apply the id to a new , to the  and now to the  but nothing works)*

---

## TL;DR:

I want to hide offline streamers in a new list but I can't use the same ID selector as I used before. How can I do it?

Comment: Can you post more of the HTML structure (like how users are nested under `#online`)? Most likely you just need to add a descendent to your `$('#online')` selector to get this working

Comment: why do you need a different class for each streamer? If anything, each streamer should have a unique ID and then you can have a class `.streamer`, `.online`, `.offline`, etc. to apply styles to all of them.

Comment: Can you post your sample html on https://jsfiddle.net please?

Comment: @RobM. Hey Rob, actually it's a normal table but I'll include a [jsfiddle]
(https://jsfiddle.net/dnso0wp2/1/).
So like I already said I want to colorize them but also add an extra list with every streamer which only shows the online streamers! :)

Comment: @Polyov How do you mean that?

Comment: @Camirlot I'm just confused by your naming scheme. Each streamer's name is an element in a list, right? So each element should have one id, the name. And then you apply classes based on the status of the user. Here you're using classes as ids, but also ids as ids? It seems like the convention you've made for yourself is too complicated, that's why you're getting tripped up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much to start with, but if you have a structure like

```
    <table>
        <tr class="header Peter" id ="onlinePeter">
            <td>Peter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="header John" id ="onlineJohn">
            <td>John</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="header Michael" id ="onlineMichael">
            <td>Michael</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="header Bob" id ="onlineBob">
            <td>Bob</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="header Daniel" id ="onlineDaniel">
            <td>Daniel</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

and a script like

```
var user = "John";
$("#online".concat(user)).css("display", "none");
user = "Daniel"
$(".".concat(user)).css("background","lightgrey");
```

It works. the row that contains John disappears

On the other piece of code where you try to change the background color, you are calling an element with the class = user, but the HTML you provided only has the class "header", once the class is added, the background changes as well.

Comment: Hey, I'm trying like you described but it don't want to work.
`$("#onlineStreamer".concat(user)).css("display", "none");
        <tr class="header" id ="onlineStreamer">`

Any other idea why it's not working? :/

Comment: "#onlineStreamer".concat(user) = "#onlineStreamerUser" Make sure that user is the second part of the ID because it will be added to the string provided.  Additionally, Remember that ID is supposed to be used by only 1 element. if you have several elements with the same ID jQuery will behave unexpectedly or not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the jsfiddle you linked and got a better understanding of what is happening.

The server returns an empty stream all the time, so the code never goes into the "true" part of the statement. Furthermore, in the "false" part of the statement, the code changes the background color and then hides the table cell.

```
 function colorize(user){
     $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/'+user, function(channel) {
         /*
         * Stream always returns as null
         */

         console.log(channel["stream"]); // returns null in all tests
         var data = channel["stream"]; // data == null
         var boolAnswer = ((typeof(data) !== 'undefined') && (data !== null));
         console.log(data);
         if ( boolAnswer === true) {
             $( ".".concat(user) ).css("background-color", "lightgreen");
             /*
             * boolAnswer is always null, so this piece is skipped all the time
             */
         }
         else if ( boolAnswer === false){
             /*
             * First it changes the color and then it hides it
             */
             $(".".concat(user)).css("background-color","lightgrey");
             $(".".concat(user)).css("display", "none");

         }
     }).success(function(response){
         console.log(response);
     });
 }

colorize('jankos'); //hides the cell of jankos
colorize(); // doesn't do anything
```

if you comment the line that says 
                 $(".".concat(user)).css("display", "none");

```
colorize('jankos'); //changes the color of the cell of jankos  
colorize() // still doesn't do anything
```